# Owl Carousel displays more items than instructed

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

Despite specifying one item when calling it [on my page](http://goo.gl/cCigPG) (password: "shooga1", pick a language then visit the [same link](http://goo.gl/cCigPG) again):

```
$('#page-lookbook-single-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items: 1, 
    navigation: true 
});
```

Owl Carousel jQuery plugin displays more than one item at certain smartphone/tablet resolutions (please reduce browser window width to see in action). In this case it breaks the layout completely.

How to enforce the instruction of 1 item only at all resolutions ?

Comment: your link isn't working: " maintenance mode"

Comment: Forgot about that sorry, I edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use option `singleItem: true` - http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html